# Servlet principal in high precedence filter, using Spring Security

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-security, spring-boot, servlet-filters

Our Spring Boot 1.3.3 application uses Spring Security. We need to log HTTP requests including requested URL, HTTP verb, processing time, user principal.

This is done using a custom servlet filter.

The custom filter must have **higher** precedence (i.e. smaller order) than Spring Security filter chain, or else it won't be executed for requests rejected by Spring Security.

But then in the custom filter, HttpServletRequest:getUserPrincipal is **always null**. It seems that Spring Security removes security information once his security chain is done.

Is there a standard way (meaning without thread local magic) to always get the user principal from a custom filter when using Spring Security?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you are using Spring Security, the principal is likely to be set precisely by the Spring Security machinery. But what's even worse, is that it uses request wrapping, so you will not find the principal neither before calling the FilterChain because it has not been set, nor after because it was set in a HttpServletRequestWrapper that is no longer here.

So IMHO your best choice is to put a custom filter inside the Spring Security chain, just before the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, log after chaining and pass along any exception.